# How can we prevent somebody else pointing their domain name to our EC2 servers?

Tags: dns, amazon-route53

One of the popular social website accidentally pointed out their domain name to an old AWS EC2 instance IP which was newly regenerated as our instance IP. Because of this when we searched for our product name in google search their website was top listed.

Now this issue has been fixed they are now back to pointing their own EC2 instances but the google search issue remains. This might take some time to get fixed because their's is a high traffic website and ours is just a new launched startup.

How can we prevent somebody else pointing their domain name to our EC2 servers?

Comment: You can't. But you can configure your server not to serve any content unless your domain name was used.

Comment: Thanks @DusanBajic . I tried to find out how to do that but couldn't. Can you suggest how to serve content only when my domain name is used?

Comment: That depends on webserver software you are using (apache httpd, nginx,...). Also share your current config.